# on select from list, text from text box not appearing by ng-model

Tags: angularjs

1) Click on list

2) press enter in text box. then in console it should print text box value

Here is the code:

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryarjnfe/6/)

```
    <div ng-app="app">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left ng-scope" ng-submit="click(select)" ng-controller="one">
        <input ng-model="select">

            <ul class="datalist ng-pristine ng-valid" id="selectClientList" ng-model="getSelect" style="display: block; top: 42px; left: 15px; width: 195px; opacity: 1;">
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope">5 Takes</li>
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope">AP Trail Mix</li>
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope">AX</li><
li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Air New Zealand</li>
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope">American Legacy Foundation</li>
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Amway</li>
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Animal Planet Meerkats</li>
</ul>

          </form>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('one', function($scope) {
        $scope.click = function() {
            console.log($scope.select);
        }
    });


// from like query plugin

$("ul li").on("click", function(){
    $("input").val($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have click function which updates the model like -

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('one', function($scope) {
        $scope.click = function() {
            console.log($scope.select);
        }
         $scope.change = function(value) {
           $scope.select=value
        }
    });
```

You link would be like -

```
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="change('5 Takes')">5 Takes</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, But i am appending list dynamically.... and on click of list $scope.change is not triggering for me......

Comment: please share plunker or jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could go about fixing it, but I think your problems stem from using bits of angular and bits of jQuery.

Your life will usually be easier with Angular if you let it handle data and updating the DOM, rather than doing it with separate functions.

Here is a fiddle where I reworked your code to use Angular binding to do all the updating automatically, so that all you need to do is update model values on a click:

https://jsfiddle.net/7q29ygmo/

So that jQuery function is now just

```
$scope.setSelect = function (item) {
        $scope.select = item;
    };
```